# How do I externally backup my Switch game saves?

Tags: nintendo-switch

When selling a Nintendo Switch, how can I backup game save content so I can access it in the future? I know Nintendo Online has game save backup for the duration of the subscription but I'm looking for something lasting longer, since it doesn't make sense to pay for a subscription without having the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Nintendo Support Q&A](https://www.nintendo.com/my/support/qa/detail/33844), this unfortunately cannot be done.

> Save data (saved game progress and related achievements, etc.) is without exception stored in the system memory. It cannot be moved or saved onto a microSD card.

So, it would seem the only way to backup Switch saves is to use Nintendo's online services for their cloud backups.

Comment: You can also transfer saves to a second nearby Switch (System Settings > Data Management > Transfer Your Save Data > Send Save Data to Another Console), but that deletes the save from the original console, so is no good as a backup.